# Removing the extra padding of the widget

Tags: html, wordpress, css, web

I want to decrease the extra grey area of the right hand side of the "property search" widget at the top. The website is a wordpress. Can someone help please?

The link is as follows:

```
http://192.254.143.28
```

Comment: Perhaps there is something to do with the css here.

Comment: Waiting for the CSS of that "widget"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you want us to help you, you should provide us with the code and not just an ip-adress.. Perhaps a jsfiddle with the working example..

Comment: Sorry. I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: There is an edit button under your question. You can use it to improve your question, so that more people will read and understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this code to your stylesheet, you just need to reduce the `width` of the `property-search` container:

```
.property-search-container.type1 {
    width: 581px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I searched the editor but there are multiple .property-search-container.type1

Comment: Should i edit them or add your code?

Comment: inside the `style.css` file of your theme, you can find the styles for `.property-search-container.type1`around line 1291. The current width is set to `700px`. You can simply reduce that or put the code which I've given above at the bottom of your stylesheet.

Comment: Can you tell me how do i save the changes please. I am sorry. i am <24 at wordpress

Comment: If you're using the Wordpress Editor to make changes to your `style.css` file then there should be a button underneath the editor which would say `Update File`. Simply click on that button and the changes would get saved.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such button. do i have to install the wordpress editor or something?

Comment: I believe you will need to make changes to the `style.css` file by accessing it through the FTP or cPanel then.

Answer (score 0):

```
.property-search-container.type1 {
   background: #f3f3f3;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 585px;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

Change the CSS above to change the size of the grey box.
Play around with the **width** property to fit your need

Answer (score 0):

modified your style of this selector. and replaced `width: auto`.

```
.property-search-container.type1 {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `width: auto;` from `.property-search-container.type1 .dt-sc-tabs-container` that will make your white box to fit in grey box. Then decrease the size of grey box by reducing width of `.property-search-container.type1`